# Installing sound card on ec2 ubuntu

Tags: sound

I have some application that needs sound card support, and I'm using a ec2 ubuntu. Can anyone advise how to install something like snd-dummy?

Answer (score 0):

#### Possible candidates

[“Dummy Output” sound in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/461716/38988)

[How to create a dummy sound card device in Linux server?](https://superuser.com/q/344760/112557)

Detailed guide:
[ALSA - Matrix:Module-dummy](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix%3aModule-dummy)

Answer (score 0):

EC2 AMIs use aws ubuntu kernel modules instead of the ubuntu generic modules, *which omits alsa sound drivers*

snd-dummy and other alsa drivers were added to the `linux-modules-extras` for Ubuntu Jammy (22.04).

So you will need to use a base ami with this version of ubuntu or later.

To install the extra modules you can run this command:

```
apt install linux-modules-extra-`uname -r`
```

After that you can do modprob and modinfo on snd-dummy